# Import data from closed excel File

Tags: excel, vba

I know this question has been answered on the site in a few examples however using any of the examples on here I've still been unable to get them to work. Here is what I have, I get an issue when it comes to `Set rng1 = b1.sht1.Range("A1")`. I'm new to coding and this looks logical but can't figure it out any help would be appreciated. Is all I need to do is in an open excel file is open another and copy data from `sheet1` to the data tab in the open workbook.

```
Sub OpenWorkbookToPullData()
    Dim path As String
    path = "S:\GAM\Middle Office\Equity Admin\aa_RawDataFiles\CollateralUtilisation.xls"

    Dim currentWb As Workbook
    Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim openWb As Workbook
    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)

    Dim openWs As Worksheet
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim b1 As Workbook
    Dim b2 As Workbook

    Set b1 = Workbooks("CollateralUtilisation.xls")
    Set b2 = Workbooks("Collateral Management.xlsm")

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = b1.Sheets(1)
    Set sht2 = b2.Sheets("DATA")

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = b1.sht1.Range("A1")
    Set rng2 = sht2.Range("A1")

    rng1 = rng2

    Debug.Print "rng1 holds: "; rng1 & vbNewLine & "rng2 holds: " & rng2


    'openWb.Close (False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Set rng1 = b1.sht1.Range("A1")
```

to

```
Set rng1 = sht1.Range("A1")
```

You don't need the `b1`. `Sht1` has already been defined using `b1` in `Set sht1 = b1.Sheets(1)`

It's like what you did for `Set rng2 = sht2.Range("A1")`

Use ADO to import from closed Excel Files. You may also want to see [Import data from a closed workbook (ADO) using VBA in Microsoft Excel](http://www.exceltip.com/import-and-export-in-vba/import-data-from-a-closed-workbook-ado-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html)

Comment: I thought I had written it that way as well and it still didn't work but I have tried again and it works fine, the problem now is I get an error on the debug line. When I remove this the data is cut from the closed excel sheet but doesn't paste in the open sheet.

Comment: Is your open sheet `openWs`?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question?

Comment: I asked, which is your open sheet? `openWs`?

Comment: open.Ws is the closed sheet in workbook Set b1 = Workbooks("CollateralUtilisation.xls")

Comment: If you can't answer my question clearly, I can't help you! You said in the first comment that `....doesn't paste in the open sheet` I am asking you now for the LAST TIME. Which is your open sheet? `openWs`? `Sht1`?, `Sht2`?